# Script overwrite ip address

Tags: linux

write script which Will be overwritten `IP` address in `/etc/network/interfaces` and  Make sure that the interface is correct than ping google.com if time result > `30 ms` reboot interface

but this code does not working properly.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "lets start ip configuratioon ...."

lastconf=$(cat /etc/network/interfaces | awk '{print $1}')
if [ ! -z $lastconf ]; then
    sed -i "/auto $lastconf/,/auto.*/{/auto.*/b;d;};" /etc/network/interfaces
    sed -i "/auto $lastconf/d" /etc/network/interfaces
echo "Now last ip configuration will be removed :)))"

ipconf="auto $lastconf\niface $lastconf inet static\n\taddress 192.168.1.2\n\tnetmask 255.255.255.0\n\tgateway 192.168.1.1\n\tdns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 192.168.0.2
echo -e $ipconf >> /etc/network/interfaces

ifconfig $lastconf down && ifconfig $lastconf up
service networking restart

pinging=$(ping google.com -c 1 | grep '64 bytes')
if [ -z $pinging ]; then
        exit 0
fi

if [ $pinging -gt 30 ]; then
        echo "request timee is more than 30wami; restarti daicko"
        ifconfig $lastconf down && ifconfig $lastconf up
        service networking restart
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: are you getting any error ? what you mean code is not working

Comment: i do not know but lecturer say that seconds are equal to each other and it's always false.

Comment: you should extract the response time from the ping command. otherwise $pinging will have text like this "64 bytes from.......blah.....". include awk command to extract the response time. use = as seperator